# Save audio stream to mp3 file (iOS)

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, ios7, core-audio

I have an AVSpeechSynthesizer which converts text to speech, but i've encountered a problem.

I don't know how to save the audio file that it generates to a music file, which I would quite like to be able to do!

So here's my question, how do you save the AVSpeechSynthesizer output and if this isn't possible, can I us AVFoundation, CoreMedia or other public API to capture the output of the speakers, but before it has come out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is no public API available to capture the speaker output and looking over the docs for AVSpeechSynthesizer and related classes I don't see a way to capture any audio from it. You may want to look at 3rd party libraries to help with this.

Related questions:

[Recording audio output only from speaker of iphone excluding microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540690/recording-audio-output-only-from-speaker-of-iphone-excluding-microphone)

[Text-to-speech libraries for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839671/text-to-speech-libraries-for-iphone/12839821#12839821)

Comment: Any private api ways to do this? :p

Comment: @HBellamy, I wish I could help there but I don't know how or what APIs to use.