# Swift: How to Convert Text-to-Speech Generated Audio to .mp3?

Tags: ios, swift, mp3

I have converted text to speech using the `AVSpeechSynthesizer`. When clicked on Play, converted speech plays. I don't know the extension of this audio file.
 My goal is to convert this created audio file to .mp3. I have searched in Google but I didn't find anything. Any help is appreciated.

My code is here: Convert text to speech

```
text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "TextString")!
voice = selectCountryDic["Clanguage"]!
let speechText = AVSpeechUtterance(string:text)
speechText.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language:voice)

let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synthesizer.speak(speechText)
```

Answer (score 5):

**2021-02-20 Update:**

This is possible now. Please see the thread: [AVSpeechSynthesizer output as file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965601/avspeechsynthesizer-output-as-file)

**2017 Answer (outdated):** 
A simple strategy would be saving your output from `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to a directory first, then changing its format. 
But, as far as I know, `AVSpeechSynthesizer` does not let you save your outputs.
I would suggest you check the following post: [Save audio stream to mp3 file (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013076/save-audio-stream-to-mp3-file-ios)

 Quoting from **IanStallings**:

> Unfortunately no, there is no public API available to capture the speaker output, and looking over the docs for AVSpeechSynthesizer and related classes I don't see a way to capture any audio from it. You may want to look at 3rd party libraries to help with this.

And another one: [AVSpeechSynthesizer output as file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965601/avspeechsynthesizer-output-as-file)

Again, quoting from **Bhumit Mehta**:

> As of now AVSpeechSynthesizer does not support this. There is no way to get the audio file using AVSpeechSynthesizer. I tried this a few weeks ago for one of my apps and found out that it is not possible, Also nothing has changed for AVSpeechSynthesizer in iOS 8.

Comment: It is possible now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965601/avspeechsynthesizer-output-as-file

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Daniel! I'll update my answer accordingly.