# Swift - How can I convert Saved Audio file conversations to Text?

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, avaudioplayer, text-to-speech

I work on speech recognition. I solve the text-to-speech and speech-to-text with IOS frameworks. But now i want to convert saved audio file conversations to text. How can i solve this ? Thank you for all replies.

Comment: please look into it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47330346/3278326

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have worked on same things which are working for me.

I have audio file in my project bundle which. So I have written following code to convert audio to text.

```
let audioURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Song", withExtension: "mov")

let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: audioURL!)

request.shouldReportPartialResults = true

if (recognizer?.isAvailable)! {

    recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in
        guard error == nil else { print("Error: \(error!)"); return }
        guard let result = result else { print("No result!"); return }

        print(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
    }
} else {
    print("Device doesn't support speech recognition")
}
```

First get audio url from where you have store audio file.
Then create instance of `SFSpeechRecognizer` with locale that you have want.
Create instance of `SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest` which are used to requesting `recognitionTask`.

`recognitionTask` will give you result and error. Where result contains `bestTranscription.formattedString`. `formmatedString` is your test result of audio file.

If set `request.shouldReportPartialResults = true`, this will give your partial result of every line speak in audio.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Dude it works. The difference between speech-to-text just change "SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest" to "SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest" i think.

Comment: In above code we give url of song or mp3 file added to bundle

Comment: Does this work with URL from database?

Comment: I tried this but for some reason I get `[Utility] +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"
Error: Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"`