# Swift - How to save a text file from speech

Tags: ios, swift, text, save

I am working on Speech to Text Application in iOS.

Actually I already made it but my actual problem is when speech is converted in text how can I save the text file in txt in specified location?

Comment: Hello! Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329826/swift-how-to-convert-text-to-speech-generated-audio-to-mp3

Comment: Your question is really about how to save a text file. So this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-a-string-from-text-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read and write a String from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-a-string-from-text-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
guard let path = try? FileManager.default.url(
    for: .documentDirectory, 
    in: .userDomainMask, 
    appropriateFor: nil, 
    create: false
).appendingPathComponent("Folder/File.txt") else {
    return 
}

try? "Text".write(to: path, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)`
```